# Swift: Decoding an array of objects returned in API call

Tags: json, swift, api, decoding

I've gone completey blank on this. I'm hitting an API which returns the following array of objects:

```
[{
    "flightNumber": "VS0012",
    "aircraftReg": "GAAAA",
    "dateTime": "2015-12-16T16:49:14+0000",
    "fuelGrade": "Jet A-1",
    "freezePoint": "-47",
    "supplier": "stage",
    "specificGravity": "798"
}, {
    "flightNumber": "BA0234",
    "aircraftReg": "GAAAA",
    "dateTime": "2016-01-11T17:53:23+0000",
    "fuelGrade": "Jet A-1",
    "freezePoint": "-47",
    "supplier": "stage",
    "specificGravity": "797"
}]
```

I created a model to decode it like this:

```
struct LastTenOrders: Codable {
    let flightNumber: String?
    let aircraftReg: String?
    let dateTime: String?
    let fuelGrade: String?
    let freezePoint: String?
    let supplier: String?
    let specificGravity: String?
}
```

I just want to know whether I'm having a complete brain freeze or whether this is indeed the correct structure I should be using.

Comment: Looks correct, if you expect some values to be missing - otherwise, best not to make them optionals. And of course, don't forget to decode as `[LastTenOrders].self`

Comment: lol that was it. Was decoding as LastTenOrders.self. Stupid mistake. Thanks so much :)

Comment: If you make everything optional, you're just going to have a life of pain, unwrapping all over the place. Unwrap once, at the point where you decode your JSON. The only optional values should be those which are *actually* optional, for business logic reasons. What exactly does it mean to have a fuel order where *all* its value are `nil`? What can you even do with such a non-sensical object?

Comment: I won't have them all as optional in the final app. However, a lot of the values will be. There are only 3 values which will be returned in each and every API call - flightNumber, aircraftReg and dateTime

Comment: @DevB1 Then you should subdivide the remaining fields according to how they can be optional. E.g. if `fuelGrade` and `freezePoint` are always nil or non-nil together, you should make a seperate `FuelDetails` model, and make a `let fuelDetails: FuelDetails?`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thanks for the tip - will defo do that once I've finalised how the object will look. Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes its good enough .. you can use `typeAlias` like this

```
typealias AllOrders = [LastTenOrders]

let orders = try JSONDecoder().decode(AllOrders.self, from: jsonData)
```

or you can directly do

```
let orders = try? JSONDecoder().decode([LastTenOrders].self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: But this is not what OP asked about.

Comment: he accepted answer i dont know why ... if it was not asked sir ...

Comment: please unaccept the answer if it did not helped ... i will delete my answer :)